# Will samsung GS 4 be a Large or Normal sized device for Android layout purposes?

Tags: android, android-layout, galaxy

The upcoming Samsung Galaxy S4.

Reported Specs: 
1080 x 1920
4.99 inch diagonal

If I plug that into a new Device definition in AVD, the resulting device size is listed as "Normal" and the Density as "xxhdpi", screen ratio long.

**However** if I put in a diagonal of **5.00** inches the size changes to "Large".

What to tust?

**More generally:** Does the AVD device manager match exactly the logic used on Android devices in determining what layout bucket to pull from (unless manufacturer overrides)?

*Edit: note regarding the above sentence: When you enter the diagonal and screen dimensions the AVD dropdowns will automatically configure themselves according to those values.*

*And please oh please don't direct me to the dreaded "Supporting Multiple Screens" page which does not give exact logic.*

Comment: Typically it's better to avoid the `large` and `xlarge` qualifiers for devices running 3.2 or higher, and use the new `sw<xxx>dp` qualifiers to determine which layout to use.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out whether I need to rush out a new release or not. If it pulls from large, then I need a new release. If it pulls from normal I do not.

Answer (score 1):

> Will samsung GS 4 be a Large or Normal sized device for Android layout purposes?

You will know when everybody else knows, when the device ships. Samsung can choose whatever it wants for the screen size.

> Does the AVD device manager match exactly the logic used on Android devices in determining what layout bucket to pull from (unless manufacturer overrides)?

No, the "AVD device manager" uses whatever screen size bucket you chose when you created the device definition. There is a drop-down listing the various choices.

Comment: Sorry but your comment "...uses whatever bucket you choose", is not what I'm talking about. If you use the device manager to setup a new device you'll notice (at least in my version) that the drop downs for setting the size and dpi buckets will change automatically when you enter the dimensions and diagonal data. Does that match to what a device pulls from (unless manufacturer overrides).

Comment: Yes, clearly I will know the answer when Samsung ships and someone reports the info. Occasionally though, people on Stackoverflow know a bit more than the general public :)

Comment: @Fraggle: "unless manufacturer overrides" -- AFAIK, there is no "unless". AFAIK, every single Android device ever manufactured has an explicit statement of what size bucket to use, as part of its firmware. The AVD device definition drop-down probably defaults to the calculations shown on the documentation page that you disparaged in your question.

Comment: That's actually useful information (that it is specified in firmware). I would have assumed that they merely specify the screen size and resolution and then let the Android OS determine the rest. But I guess that's not the case (link?). Yes I disparaged that page because it does not give an exact way to determine the size bucket.

Comment: @Fraggle: I know that density is set in `build.prop`. I would have assumed that the size bucket would be there as well, but I am not finding any citations for that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that density bucket thresholds are defined by Android but manufacturers are free to enter any dpi in build.prop. In the case of Galaxy Tab 7.7 (1280x780), I used to own, Samsung set the dpi same as the larger galaxy tab 10.1 (1280x780), thus it runs in MDPI (i.e. tiny buttons) - but this was before Nexus 7 defined the "phablet" UI.